# How do I convert a 'Fixnum' to a date in Rails 3.1.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display this output, as a date:

```
1296524384
```

But when I call `.to_date` on it, I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `to_date' for 1296524384:Fixnum
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just do:

```
the_time = Time.at(1296524384)
```

That gives you:

> 2011-01-31 20:39:44 -0500

By the way, `1296524384` is referred to as UNIX or epoch time.  It measures the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970.

To format it a bit better, you can use Ruby's `strftime` method.

```
the_time = Time.at(1296524384).strftime("The date is %m/%d/%Y")
```

More info here:  http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Comment: That sure does give me `2011-12-04 21:26:36 -0500`, but how do I get it in a more 'human-friendly' format?